# update table with csv using laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, maatwebsite-excel

I'm trying to update a table using Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel.

```
public function import(Request $request)
{
  if($request->file('imported-file'))
  {
            $path = $request->file('imported-file')->getRealPath();
            $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader)
      {
            })->get();

      if(!empty($data) && $data->count())
      {
        foreach ($data->toArray() as $row)
        {
          if(!empty($row))
          {
            $dataArray[] =
            [
              //'name' => $row['name'],
              'age' => $row['age'],
              'phone' => $row['phone'],
              //'created_at' => $row['created_at']
            ];
          }
          if(!empty($dataArray))
            {
                //Item::insert($dataArray);
                DB::table('items')
                ->where('name', $row['name'])->update($dataArray);

                return view('imported')->with('success', 'Course updated');
            }
      }

     }
   }
}
```

But its giving error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: update items set 0 = 20 where name = james

Here's my csv

```
name,age,phone
James,20,888839939
Joseph,54,3444444
Hanson,30,99999999
```

The above is the csv file i'm trying to update.

Comment: What is the error that you get.

Comment: @TheFallen SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: update `items` set `0` = 20 where `name` = james

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$dataArray` is an array of arrays, so to make it work you have to loop each one:

```
if(!empty($dataArray)) {
    foreach ($dataArray as $array) {
        DB::table('items')
            ->where('name', $row['name'])
            ->update($array);
    }

    return view('imported')->with('success', 'Course updated');
}
```

But this wouldn't make much sense, because every time it would be updating the row with **name = $row['name']**, so you probbaly need to update the line where you set a value to the `$dataArray` from **$dataArray[] = ...** to **$dataArray = ...***, so it could have a single value.

Comment: This worked partially, only the first row of the file was picked, the other rows was ignore. I tried updating $dataArray[] = ... to $dataArray = ...* but it threw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

In case any body comes across this, this is how i solved it.

```
public function import(Request $request)
    {
      if($request->file('imported-file'))
      {
                $path = $request->file('imported-file')->getRealPath();


                Excel::load($path)->each(function (Collection $csvLine) {


                    DB::table('items')
                        ->where('id', $csvLine->get('id'))
                        ->update(['name' => $csvLine->get('name'),'phone' => $csvLine->get('phone'),'age' => $csvLine->get('age')]);

               });
               return view('imported')->with('success', 'Course updated');


       }
    }
```

I used the each() collection method to loop through the csv file and it won the battle.